# How to use bitcoinjs with TestNet?

Tags: testnet, bitcoinjs

One of my colleagues is trying to use bitcoinjs with TestNet, but apparently it doesn't like TestNet headers, so it doesn't work. Is there any way to make to use bitcoinjs with TestNet? Is there some specific configuration needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run your bitcoinjs-server exit with --testnet.

```
bitcoinjs run --testnet
```

[Source](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-server#usage)

Are there any existing public bitcoinjs exits running in testnet mode? I don't know.